# cudaSafeCall() runtime API error

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to run CUDA in emulation mode in Visual Studio 2008.

It is showing this problem at runtime:

```
cudaSafeCall() Runtime API error in file <xyz>, line abc : feature is not implemented
```

for example in one case it turned out to be this one:

```
cutilSafeCall(cudaGLRegisterBufferObject(pbo));
```

and if I commented this one out then:

```
cutilSafeCall( cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_triangle_p, triangle_size));
```

Is this because I am running the code in emulation mode? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Seems like this isn't a problem with cutilSafeCall() it's the underlying calls to cudaGLRegisterBufferObject and cutilSafeCall which fail.

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the most probable reason for this is a mismatch between libraries. For example you're building against the debug library cudartD.dll but loading the release version. Alternatively you could be using another library which was built in release and now loaded against your project which is build for debug, the CUDA utils library cutil which comes with the samples is an obvious candidate.

Without more details it's hard to say anything further.